# MySql Not Exists query extremely slow when joined with other indexes

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM accounts a WHERE 
    type = 0 AND status = -1 
    AND not exists (select 1  from user_filters  b  where a.id = b.account_id and b.user_id = 9  limit 1);
```

This takes around 7 seconds to respond. However, if I only run the `type = 0 and status = -1` part or the `not exists` subquery, they all finish in less than one second.

What is a better approach to make this query faster?

These are MyISAM tables, and the type and status columns are in a combined index. The user_filters table consists of composite primary keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM accounts a
WHERE type = 0 AND status = -1 AND
      not exists (select 1
                  from user_filters uf
                  where a.id = uf.account_id and uf.user_id = 9
                 );
```

You want indexes on `accounts(type, status, id)` and `user_filters(account_id, user_id)`.  Your description suggests that you have the first index or close enough.

Comment: Accounts.id is a primary key. Are you suggesting I make a composite index on it too?

Comment: Did that, and it worked, thanks! I could not believe I need an index in addition to the primary key. My reputation is too low (bc of the downvote) so I could not upvote your answer

Comment: @DavidC. Indexes properly implemented work wonders.  Now you may upvote. Welcome to SO.